# How to have a path containing spaces in PATH?

Tags: ubuntu-one, bash

I tried

export `TASK=$HOME/Ubuntu\ One` and export `TASK="$HOME/Ubuntu One"`

but neither works.

Comment: `TASK` or `PATH`?  Are you setting `PATH` using `TASK`?  If so, how?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not the definition you're having issues with, it's the use.You need to wrap wherever you're using the variable in quotes. See this example:

```
oli@bert:~/Music$ export B="$HOME/Music/Yeah Yeah Yeahs/"
oli@bert:~/Music$ cd $B
-bash: cd: /home/oli/Music/Yeah: No such file or directory
oli@bert:~/Music$ cd "$B"
oli@bert:~/Music/Yeah Yeah Yeahs$
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
export TASK="$HOME/Ubuntu\ One"
```

In both exports you issued, when you echo $TASK, the result is

```
/home/user/Ubuntu One
```

This is not the expected behavior because when you write something like

```
cp $TASK/file somewhere_else/
```

bash will expand it to

```
cp /home/user/Ubuntu One/file somewhere_else/
```

which is, of course, incorrect.

Therefore, we need to put our path in quotation marks, *and* escape the space.

Comment: That's wrong.  Did you try it?  If you do this, cp sees the backslash, and cp doesn't handle backslashes, the shell does.

Answer (score 0):

This page explains the issue in detail. It's a good idea to read it thoroughly http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments

Answer (score 0):

This awkward and clumsy behaviour is the result of an unwise choice in the name of the "Ubuntu One" directory.  Unfortunately, there seems to be [no fix](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-client/+question/111849) planned for this.

One option is to use Dropbox, which offers similar functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than resorting to Dropbox, I made a symbolic link:

```
ln -s Ubuntu\ One UbuntuOne
```

In my particular case I wanted to import python modules from a directory on my cloud:

```
ln -s Ubuntu\ One/pythonfiles pythonfiles
export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:$HOME/pythonfiles/"
```

I agree, it is idiotic to put spaces in linux filenames.