# Exporting LD_LIBRARY_PATH that contains spaces and special characters

Tags: application-development, environment-variables, special-characters

Trying to deploy a Qt application on Ubuntu

Directions from  [Qt site](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/deployment-x11.html#application-dependencies) show how to allow the library dependencies to be loaded, by changing the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable:

```
#!/bin/sh
appname=`basename $0 | sed s,\.sh$,,`

dirname=`dirname $0`
tmp="${dirname#?}"

if [ "${dirname%$tmp}" != "/" ]; then
dirname=$PWD/$dirname
fi

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$dirname/Framework:$dirname/Libraries:{LD_LIBRARY_PATH}

export $LD_LIBRARY_PATH

$dirname/$appname "$@"
```

Unfortunately the directory where the application has to be installed - which will appear in the PWD - has spaces and special characters

```
/usr/share/My Company, Inc/ProductName/
```

Looking at resources like this: [How to have a path containing spaces in PATH?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26372/how-to-have-a-path-containing-spaces-in-path) I tried to change

```
dirname="$PWD"/$dirname
```

or even wrote it all out (just as a test, since the library path has to work from any directory not just a specific one) as

```
dirname="/usr/share/My\ Company\,\ Inc/ProductName/"
```

and

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$dirname"
```

it still says

```
./MyProgram.sh: 13: export: Company,: bad variable name
```

Changing  `export $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to  `export "$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"` leads to a new error :

```
 13: export: /usr/share/My Company, Inc/ProductName/./Framework:/usr/share/My Company, Inc/ProductName/./Libraries:: bad variable name
```

Looking at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10072609/how-to-escape-spaces-in-library-path-appended-to-ld-preload

Is this an impossible task ?

How can I make the export understand spaces and comma ?

Comment: You wrote `dirname = "/usr/share/My\ Company\,\ Inc/ProductName/"`. It should be `VAR=value` not `VAR = value`. Try again.

Comment: done - I typed that one instead of copying it from the machine - the fact that the error was at "Company," being a separate part of an invalid variable proves it

Comment: Why not just create a symbolic link to some place and avoid the whole rigmarole? `ln -s /usr/share/My\ Company\,\ Inc/ProductName/ ~/mycomp/prodname`  and then use the path to the link.

Comment: Thank you, I was thinking about it, though I may not be allowed to, I have to make an installer for a product and place the files in the (existing / used by other products) company folder. Placing additional files or links in other places may not be acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are supposed to export the variable, not its value.

I.e.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

not

```
export "$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
```

*Edit (example):*

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH='/usr/share/My Company, Inc/ProductName'
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
$ env | grep LD_
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/share/My Company, Inc/ProductName
$
```

Comment: With the resulting error " /usr/share/My: not found"... yes it is one of the versions I thought I mentioned.

Comment: @Thalia: Not as far as I can see. Please see the example I added to my answer.

Comment: You were right !